# Writing a language for the Windows Scripting Host (WSH)

Tags: programming-languages, wsh, scripting-language

Has anyone had any experience targetting `WSH` in the way that `VBScript`, `JScript`, `PerlScript`, `xbScript` and `ForthScript` (among other) do, such that the language can be used from the command line and embedded in server-side web pages? Where do I go to get that kind of information?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are called [Windows Script Engines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xawadt95(VS.85).aspx) and are implemented by exposing the engine via COM.  There is a lot documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9d4xf28(VS.85).aspx), and the actual interfaces are fairly straight forward.

Comment: So, let me get this right. What I think you are saying is that this would be the way to go about creating a new language that targets the WSH? Am I correct in thinking that?