# Creating a scripting language

Tags: windows, programming-languages, scripting, wsh

Can somebody please guide me in the right direction of creating a scripting language that targets the WSH (Windows Scripting Host)?

I have googled for it, but there seem to be far fewer links related to this than when I originally searched for it a few months back.

THank you

Comment: You may be better off building on PowerShell. You get so much more for free.  You haven't told us what your purpose is, so who knows?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174240/writing-a-language-for-the-windows-scripting-host-wsh

Comment: This should not be marked as a duplicate. Since  I was dissatisfied with the answers given for question 174240.

Comment: @j-t-s, it might be worth indicating what you felt was missing from those answers so that people can provide you with the information you were looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to find all necessary information about creating Windows Script engines on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9d4xf28.aspx); other than that there seems to be no resources available (at least I couldn't find any). You can also take a look at some open-source engine implementations to get the idea of what your code should look like:

- [PHPScript](http://pecl.php.net/package/PHPScript)
- [ActiveScriptRuby](http://www.geocities.co.jp/SiliconValley-PaloAlto/9251/ruby/main.html)
- [Open Object Rexx](http://www.oorexx.org/download.html)

If you have any *specific* questions about implementing Windows Script interfaces, feel free to ask them here. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The product is now called "Windows Script Host".  The MSDN documentation suggests that what you want is a [Windows Script Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xawadt95(VS.85).aspx), about which the documentation claims that you can create one for any programming language or environment—presumably including one you create yourself.  Beyond that, the documentation is not terribly clear.

Answer (score 0):

Topic starter need to **carefully** read the `script56.chm`, which can be found on MSDN. This help file describes WSH engine specification.