# New scripting language

Tags: c#, wsh, scripting-language

I am trying to create a scripting language by myself (it doesn't have to be perfect - although that would be great if it was), mostly because i'm doing it for fun and to learn about how they're created etc.

According to the answer over here: [Creating a scripting language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439929/creating-a-scripting-language) what I'm supposed to be looking into is this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xawadt95%28VS.85%29.aspx . But, I have absolutely no idea what that MSDN page is on about.

Can somebody please help?

P.S.
Are there any free/open source scripting languages that target the Windows Script Host, that also have full source code available for it that I can play around with?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing this for fun and to learn how languages are created, I advise you to **stay far, far away from Windows Script Host.**  Instead, try learning from better examples.  A good first step would be to get yourself on over to http://www.lua.org/, study the language, read about how it is implemented, and roll your own.  Another language that is horrible from a language point of view, but very easy to implement is [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/).  Start with Ousterhout's original Usenix paper.

I wish I could recommend a good book on designing and implementing your own programming language.  I've never seen one.  (I've seen some bad books along these lines, but not wishing to disrespect the authors, I won't identify them.)  But if you can spend some quality time in a good university library, you will be able to find some interesting papers.  You might also find it worthwhile to check our Friedman and Wand's book [*Essentials of Programming Languages*](http://eopl3.com/)—although it is very technical, it does have some good stuff about writing interpreters.  There's also a good (but very old) book by P. J. Brown called [*Writing Interactive Compilers and Interpreters*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471100722).

Comment: Windows Script Host isn't a language, it's a script host. The standard script engines it supports are VBScript and JScript but there is a 3rd party Perl engine for it as well. What puzzles me though is why Windows Script Host is an issue one way or the other here. Normally you create a script engine that has an API allowing it to be embedded within any of a number of programs. That MSDN link points to a discussion of the API a Windows Script engine must support.

Comment: @Bob: Indeed.  It's just that if OP is having trouble following the MSDN link, then j-t-s is probably better off building something standalone and getting some experience before starting to wrestle with the API.  I had a bit of trouble fighting my way through the API documentation myself, and I'm not a beginner...

Answer (score 0):

The easist way to make a simple script interrupter is by spliting your source code by the line break character into an array and cycling through each member. Here is an example
    string source = @"
    print Hello World!
    stop
    "); 
    foreach(string a in source.split('\n'))
    {
    if(a.StartsWith("print "))
    {
    Console.WriteLine(a.Substring(6));
    }
    if(a == "stop")
    {
    Console.ReadLine();
    }