# Creating a Windows Script Host Language

Tags: jscript, wsh, windows-scripting

Ok, I know I've asked this in the past (and can no longer find that question), and I know *I personally have seen **many** useful articles, documentation and tutorials* on how to do this - yet I can no longer find a single one of them on Google. So, please refrain from marking as a duplicate, unless it really does answer my question.

How can I create my own Windows Scripting Host Language? (I believe they're called "Engines"), and what tools and resources are available to aid in this journey? And is there more than one way to go about it, or are there different approaches that we can take to accomplish this?

Comment: [Writing a language for the Windows Scripting Host (WSH)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/174240/113116), [Creating a scripting language](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2439929/113116), [New scripting language](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2455032/113116)

Answer (score 1):

Starters for theory:

1. [Windows Script Interfaces Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwzhawfx%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Starters for implementation:

1. [How to add support for hosing VBScript to your MFC application](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/221992/en-us) (dated/stale)

Where to steal from:

1. Sources of ActiveState's [Perl](http://downloads.activestate.com/ActivePerl/releases/5.16.3.1603/)/Python script engines
2. [LuaScript](http://na-s.jp/LuaScript/)
3. Ruby [A](http://www.geocities.co.jp/SiliconValley-PaloAlto/9251/ruby/main.html) [B](https://github.com/arton/RScript19)